# Can you insert separators into the generated menu items for an Xcode extension's commands (under 'Editor' menu)?

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-extension

When writing an Xcode extension, any commands you define automatically appear as one long list under Xcode's 'Editor/' menu.

For instance, if you define an extension called 'My First Xcode Extension' with eight commands, it appears like this...

```
Xcode
  ├── File Menu
  ├── Edit Menu
  ├── View Menu
  ├── Find Menu
  ├── Navigate Menu
  └── Editor Menu
      ├── My First Xcode Extension <-- Your extension appears here
      │   ├── Command1             <-- All your commands are listed here
      │   ├── Command2
      │   ├── Command3
      │   ├── Command4
      │   ├── Command5
      │   ├── Command6
      │   ├── Command7
      │   └── Command8
      └── Some Other Extension
          ├── CommandA
          └── CommandB
```

However, some of the commands are related, so I want to group them, like this...

```
Xcode
  ├── File Menu
  ├── Edit Menu
  ├── View Menu
  ├── Find Menu
  ├── Navigate Menu
  └── Editor Menu
      ├── My First Xcode Extension
      │   ├── Command1
      │   ├── Command2
      │   ├── --------   <-- Need separator here
      │   ├── Command3
      │   ├── Command4
      │   ├── Command5
      │   ├── --------   <-- and here
      │   ├── Command6
      │   ├── Command7
      │   └── Command8
      └── Some Other Extension
          ├── CommandA
          └── CommandB
```

Here's an example of what I'm after
    class Extension: NSObject, XCSourceEditorExtension {

```
    var commandDefinitions: [[XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey:Any]] {

        return [

           [XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey.classNameKey  : String(reflecting:FirstCommandClass.self),
            XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey.identifierKey : "doSomething",
            XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey.nameKey       : "Do something cool"],

           [ // What goes here to create a separator...],

           [XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey.classNameKey  : String(reflecting:SecondCommandClass.self),
            XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey.identifierKey : "doSomethingElse",
            XCSourceEditorCommandDefinitionKey.nameKey       : "Do something else just as cool"]
        ]
    }
}
```

Is it possible to add a separator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That’s not currently supported.

Comment: Can you elaborate?  This isn't really a definitive answer as it gives no references, nor explanation of why this isn't supported.

Comment: “Why” questions aren’t something anyone with the internal knowledge to do so would be allowed to answer. As for whether this answer is (currently) definitive, I can assure you that it is. Watch the WWDC 2016 presentation on source editor extensions to see why what I say on the topic should be considered so.

Comment: I have seen it. However, I must've missed the portion you are referring to.  Do you know roughly whereabouts in the video it is?  I'll check it out again, but don't want to spend an hour looking for that single thing.

Comment: I’m not saying “the video says that separators aren’t supported.” I’m saying “I’m the person in the video so you can treat what I say as authoritative on the topic.”

Comment: [mic drop].  Ok... definitely can’t argue with that! Point, you, sir! :).  Thanks!

Comment: Well, I found a temporary work-around until you guys support it.  I'm using this for the label... `─` and an action that does nothing except call `completionHandler(nil)`.  Hopefully it'll come soon though! :)

Comment: By the way, mind checking out my other Xcode-extension-related question here... https://stackoverflow.com/q/49245736/168179?