# Can an Xcode Source Editor Extension prompt the user for input?

Tags: swift4, nsalert, xcode-extension

Simple question.  I've written an Xcode Source Editor Extension and as part of one of my commands, I have to prompt the user for input to know which option they want.

I'm hoping there's a simple way to present an alert, but I'm guessing that's not the case and I'll have to instead launch the app from the extension (via URL schemes), then use inter-process communications.

Like I said, hoping I'm wrong. So am I?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to prompt the user. I wanted something similar where I wanted to execute a menu command but couldn't.